# Navbar height increases when media width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very simple navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
            @Html.ActionLink("Contacts", "Contacts", "Home", null, null, null, new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand customclass" })
            @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, null, "anchor", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
                <li style="padding-right:20px"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>text</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

So when my screen goes below 768 the navbar height goes from 51 to 66 and the navbar doesn't look pretty anymore (as the button gets displaced so that it stays in the center, but the links don't), so I understand I basically have to override this with a media query of sorts, but I don't understand how. I tried setting height to 51 and it dkinda works (only for navbar height the button gets displaced slightly, trying to align with the center of navbar as if it was 66px, or maybe a padding\margin gets applied, but I was unable to find said padding\margin).

All the classes are unmodified bootstrap, I only applied my own class to make first link (in navbar) a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the navbar height isn't the right approach. It expands because margin is applied on the menu list:

```
.navbar-nav {
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
```

You can override that like so:

```
.navbar-nav {
    margin: 0 -15px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jahttc76/)**

No media query is required since this applies to the smallest breakpoint. Bootstrap CSS is applied "mobile first".

Comment: for some reason I wasn't able to locate any margin on the button with opera inspect element thingie

Comment: Updated. The list, not the button. I'm not familiar with Opera's dev tools, but it may not update as you adjust screen size.

Comment: what tools do you suggest, please?